# Paramiko SFTP error when trying to upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sftp, paramiko

This is the code:

```
@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    try:
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        print("You are uploading at", dt_string)

        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect((ip, 9090))  # Connect to server
        UUID = str(uuid.uuid4())
        header_data = "{ \n" + socket.gethostbyname(hostname) + "\n SCOPE:upload \n" + dt_string + "\n" + UUID + "\n}"
        with open("header.txt", "w") as datasave:
            datasave.write(header_data)

        client_socket.send(header_data.encode())
        data_from_server = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

        with open("header_response.txt", "w") as datasave:
            datasave.write(data_from_server)
        print(data_from_server)

        with open("header_response.txt", "r") as header_file:
            header = header_file.read()
            usr = header.split("USR: ")[1].split("\n")[0].strip()
            passwd = header.split("PASSWD: ")[1].split("\n")[0].strip()
        os.system("sudo rm header_response.txt")
        os.system("sudo rm header.txt")
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.connect(ip, username=usr, password=passwd)
        print('a trecut')
        sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        with open("data.nimb", 'w') as d:
            d.write(UUID + '\n' + dt_string + "\n")
        with open('data.nimb', 'rb') as miau:
            with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
                sftp.putfo(miau, '/incoming/' + "data.nimb")
        os.remove('data.nimb')
        code = str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999))
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password, code, uuid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (usr, passwd, code, UUID))
        con.commit()


        uploaded_filenames = []  # Initialize a list to store uploaded filenames

        for uploaded_file in request.files.getlist('file'):
            filename = uploaded_file.filename
            uploaded_filenames.append(filename)  # Save the filename to the list
            sftp.putfo(uploaded_file, '/incoming/' + filename)

        sftp.close()
        ssh.close()

        #print(uploaded_filenames)
        # Send the uploaded filenames to the specified IP address
        #send_filenames(uploaded_filename)

        return render_template('success.html', code=code, filenames=uploaded_filenames)

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()  # Print traceback information including line number
        app.logger.error('An error occurred: {}'.format(str(e)))
        # Handle the error and return an appropriate response
        return render_template('error.html', message="An error occurred")
```

This gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimbus-pi/mlrasp/web/app.py", line 81, in success
    sftp.putfo(miau, '/incoming/' + "data.nimb")
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 714, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, "wb") as fr:
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 822, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 874, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 903, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
[2023-07-15 19:57:54,939] ERROR in app: An error occurred: [Errno 2] No such file
```

I think it might be because of the ssh setting but I don't know: Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the remote user doesn't have permissions to read/write to the target directory, or that the directory doesn't exist. It might also be due to restrictions on the SSH server process itself, or that the file already exists. To eliminate code-related issues you can try using a generic sftp client to connect; check to see if you can list the remote directory's contents, get files and put files. Then check if you can chdir to `/incoming/` and check again listing, getting and putting files.
If you have admin access to the remote server, its logs could shed some more light on why the request is denied.

Also, in the following code block:

```
    with open('data.nimb', 'rb') as miau:
        with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
            sftp.putfo(miau, '/incoming/' + "data.nimb")
```

the `with paramiko...` statement is redundant. This may open a new client object into the `ssh` variable, but you've already opened a channel in the code above that. I don't think it is likely to cause the issue (as the `sftp` object used should not be overwritten), but it is possible.

Another observation is that the exception states `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file [2023-07-15 19:57:54,939]`. Since the code that fails already has the local file open and the remote filename is hardcoded to `/incoming/data.nimb`, this suggests that the remote server may be configured to add some timestamps to uploaded files, but may not properly handle spaces in filenames, or directory creation. If you have admin access to the remote server, check if it is configured to add timestamps to uploaded filenames, or to save new files under directories which contain the timestamp. If the timestamped directory doesn't exist - this may be the actual cause.